# How can i pass dictionary keys tree to function as arguments to get a value in the 4-level nested distionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested

For example - i have a multylevel nested dictionary

```
mydict = {"level00": {
                      "level01":["1","2","3"],
                      "level02":{"level10":"Value1","level11":"Value2"},
                      "level03":{"level11":{"level21":[1,2,3,4],"level22":"Value3"}
                     }
         }
```

To get a "Value3" , for example, i should set a tree of indexes like :

```
print(mydict["level00"]["level03"]["level11"]["level22"]) # will get a "Value3"
```

So my queston is , if i know all dictionary keys, how can i pass this tree as a list to a function, to get any value from the dictionary ?
Something like :

```
keylist = ["level00","level03","level11","level22"]
neededvalue = getavalue(keylist) #function to return a value from the distionary
```

keylist can be different

May be there is a way to transform a list to the indexes tree ??

Are the any other ways unless an iterations ??

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dict as described above and can create a list of keys defining the path to the value needed, you can get that value as follows:

```
mydict = {"level00": {
                      "level01":["1","2","3"],
                      "level02":{"level10":"Value1","level11":"Value2"},
                      "level03":{"level11":{"level21":[1,2,3,4],"level22":"Value3"}
                     }
         }}
keylist= ["level00", "level03",'level11' ,"level22"]
def get_innerValue(kl, md ):
    """return the value designated by the keylist, if exists"""
    rslt = md
    for k in kl:
        rslt = rslt[k]
    return rslt
```

using `get_innerValue(keylist, mydict)` yields:

```
'Value3'
```